# Delete/unset an array element matching a key/value of another array element [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following multidimensional array:

```
$messages = array(

  'message1'=>array(
    'type'=>'voice',
    'call-id'=>'11'
    'id'='message1'
  ),
  'message2'=>array(
    'type'=>'voice',
    'call-id'=>'44'
    'id'='message2'
  ),
  'message3'=>array(
    'type'=>'text',
    'call-id'=>'44'
    'id'='message3'
  ),
  'message4'=>array(
    'type'=>'text',
    'call-id'=>'55'
    'id'='message4'
  ),
  'message5'=>array(
    'type'=>'voice',
    'call-id'=>'55'
    'id'='message5'
  ),

);
```

I need to delete/unset for example $messages['message2'], because there is another array element($messages['message3']) with keys and values('type'=>'text', 'call-id'=>'44').

Basically, if we have two elements with the same call-id, then delete the element with type = voice.

So, the result of the array above should be:

```
$messages = array(

  'message1'=>array(
    'type'=>'voice',
    'call-id'=>'11'
    'id'='message1'
  ),
  'message3'=>array(
    'type'=>'text',
    'call-id'=>'44'
    'id'='message3'
  ),
  'message4'=>array(
    'type'=>'text',
    'call-id'=>'55'
    'id'='message4'
  ),

);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is your code? Please see **how to ask a good question** https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$messages = array(

  'message1'=>array(
    'type'=>'voice',
    'call-id'=>'11',
    'id'=>'message1'
  ),
  'message2'=>array(
    'type'=>'voice',
    'call-id'=>'44',
    'id'=>'message2'
  ),
  'message3'=>array(
    'type'=>'text',
    'call-id'=>'44',
    'id'=>'message3'
  ),
  'message4'=>array(
    'type'=>'text',
    'call-id'=>'55',
    'id'=>'message4'
  ),
  'message5'=>array(
    'type'=>'voice',
    'call-id'=>'55',
    'id'=>'message5'
  ),

);

$unique = [];

foreach ($messages as $value) {
    if ($value['type'] == 'text') {
        $unique[$value['call-id']] = $value;
    // so text comes first and override any previous value with the same call-id
    } else if (!array_key_exists($value['call-id'], $unique)) {
        $unique[$value['call-id']] = $value;
    // will be added only if no same call-id and will be overridden if same call-id with type text after
    }
}

foreach ($unique as $value) {
    $array[$value['id']] = $value;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
```

OUTPUT:

```
    Array
(
    [message1] => Array
        (
            [type] => voice
            [call-id] => 11
            [id] => message1
        )

    [message3] => Array
        (
            [type] => text
            [call-id] => 44
            [id] => message3
        )

    [message4] => Array
        (
            [type] => text
            [call-id] => 55
            [id] => message4
        )

)
```

http://www.phpwin.org/s/LJxrQw

Comment: That's not right. `call-id` => 55 with `type` => voice should get deleted, not text.

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen , thanks for quick reponse, but the element 'message5' should've been deleted/unset as well, and keep the element 'message4' because its type is 'text''and not voice.

Comment: Answer Updated!